# amount of gas used in receive and fallback functions in truffle tests

Tags: truffle, gas-estimate, fallback-function, solidity-0.6.x

I have a contract that is written in solidity ^0.6.4 and has a simple implementation of reverting funds when someone directly transfers some eth or calls an unhandled function. Now it appears to be working but I wanted to test it by checking the balance of the account that calls it my truffle tests. I know that there are some amount of gas being used when calling these methods but how can I get the exact amount of gas being used in a reverted call?

The way I am trying to test it is by assuming that the current balance of the caller should be its balance before the call deducted by the amount of gas used(I have written a function that would multiply gasUsed by gasPrice).

contract code :

```
receive() external payable {
        require(false , "Direct fund transfer must be reverted.");
    }

    fallback() external {} //not payable so that unhandled function calls will revert.
```

Unit test :

```
    describe('receive and fallback',async () => {
        before(async () => {
            this.originalBidder1Balance = await balance.current(bidder1); 
        })

        it('any empty calldata with value > 0 should be reverted', async () => {

            let marketplaceAddress = this.marketplace.address
            await expectRevert(
                this.marketplace.sendTransaction({from : bidder1, value : this.platformReserveInWei}),
                "Direct fund transfer to token must be reverted."
            );
            
        })

        it('funds must be reverted too', async () => {

            const tx = await this.marketplace.sendTransaction(
                 {from : bidder1, value : this.platformReserveInWei}
            ); // will revert here

            this.bidder1GasCosts = await getGasCosts(tx);
            let bidder1Balance = await balance.current(bidder1); 

            expect(bidder1Balance).to.be.bignumber.equal(this.originalBidder1Balance.sub(this.bidder1GasCosts));
        })
        
    })

    async function getGasCosts(receipt) {
        const tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(receipt.tx);
        const gasPrice = new BN(tx.gasPrice);
        return gasPrice.mul(new BN(receipt.receipt.gasUsed));
    }
```

I am using openzeppelin's test helpers. By the way is this a good practice that I used in receive() ? reverting everything I mean.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The 'funds must be reverted too' test is redundant (let alone, it assumes that a previous "it" has been executed, which is generally a bad practice).

Comment: Well, it's not just about the test, I personally value strictly testing above everything, cause it also helps me learn and understand at a deeper level.

Can you please elaborate a little bit more on the note inside the parenthesis?